# Adding Datasource to ReqTransPOListPage

Tags: axapta, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I'm trying to add a field from EcoResProduct to the form ReqTransPOList page but can't seem to figure it out. I've added the datasource to the query but it won't let me add any fields from it to the form. I can create a new view and adding fields to that is fine, but just can't to the form itself.

I haven't dealt much with interaction classes, am I missing something associated with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has the easiest, yet hardest to find solution. Even though the data source was showing in the form I had to select the Data Source head and select the Query line in the properties and hit enter(you don't need to change it, just hit enter). This apparently forces a refresh that compiling, restoring, restarting AOS, and export/import couldn't do.

Comment: That is, you have to refresh the query, re associate it with the from :)

Comment: @maqk Not exactly. If you change a query you typically just have to restore the form to get the changes, but that wasn't the case here. An ERP system shouldn't make you reselect the same value from a pick list.